# Ошибка при подключении keras

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras

У меня возникает ошибка при подключении keras.

```
import keras
```

> ```
> TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-5-84252b6afce3> in <module>()
>   1 from __future__ import print_function
>   2 import numpy as np
> ----> 3 import keras
>   4 from keras.datasets import mnist
>   5 from keras.models import Sequential
>
> ~/python/keras.py in <module>()
>  53 
>  54 
> ---> 55 show_tags.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W)
>  56 trunc_page.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)
>  57 next_button.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=S)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py in grid_configure(self, cnf,**kw)
>  2218         self.tk.call(
>  2219               ('grid', 'configure', self._w)
> -> 2220               + self._options(cnf, kw))
> 2221     grid = configure = config = grid_configure
> 2222     bbox = grid_bbox = Misc.grid_bbox
>
> TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!frame2 which already has slaves managed by pack
> ```

keras 2.1.6
Python 3.6
conda 4.4.11

Работаю в Jupyter Notebook, устанавливала keras и через `pip`, и через `conda`. Ошибка не пропадала.

Comment: попробуйте импортировать `keras` из `ipython` - воспроизводится ли ошибка в этом случае?

Comment: @MaxU ошибки нет https://screenshots.firefox.com/Ar6qiJc1dQ9smSP2/localhost